# Java Applet GUI positions

Tags: java, applet, vertical-alignment, jlabel, jtextfield

This is a mysterious problem. I have a `JSlider`, `JLabel`, and `JTextField`. I want them to be all adjacently aligned. My problem is that the `JTextField`'s (valueField) is shifted up. When I print out the values of the y-coordinate between the components, they are all the same. Here is my code for the `JLabel` and the `JTextField`:

```
public SliderLabelPanel(String labelStr, String unitLabelStr)
//PRE:  labelStr is initialized  
//POST: a default SliderLabelPanel is created
{
    //this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    slider.setMaximum(100);
    slider.setMinimum(0);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);

    label = new JLabel(labelStr);
    valueField = new JTextField();
    unitLabel = new JLabel(unitLabelStr);

    this.add(slider);
    this.add(label);
    this.add(valueField);
    this.add(unitLabel);
    //printFields();
}

public void update()
//POST: this SliderLabelPanel is updated (size of the components)
{
    this.slider.setBounds(0, slider.getY(), (int)(Global.sliderWidth * getWidth()), (int)(Global.labelHeight * getHeight()));
    this.label.setBounds(slider.getX() + slider.getWidth(), slider.getY(), 
                        Global.LABEL_WIDTH, (int)(Global.labelHeight * getHeight()));

    this.valueField.setBounds(label.getX() + label.getWidth(), slider.getY(),
                             (int)(Global.fieldWidth * getWidth()), Global.FIELD_HEIGHT);

    //valueField.getx

    this.unitLabel.setBounds(valueField.getX() + valueField.getWidth(), slider.getY(),
                             Global.LABEL_WIDTH, (int)(Global.labelHeight * getHeight()));
    printFields();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
//PRE:  g is initialized
//POST: the components of this SliderLabelPanel are painted to g
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

The `JSlider` will be aligned with the `JLabel`, however the `JTextField` will be shifted up. Please give me suggestions as well, I am running out of ideas. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Your post and code as written hardly testable for us. Please create and post a small compilable program that shows your problem, a program complete enough so that it will compile and run for us, but small enough so that it can be understood quickly, an [sscce](http://sscce.or).

Comment: And in fact, I've posted this suggestion before to you, and have shown you an example SSCCE in your most recent question. Please put in the same effort asking your question that I've already put in answering your last question. It's not asking too much.

Comment: Why are you using [Absolute Positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. Alright, I'll post it after I check out the other solution.

Comment: @trashgod, Could you give me some suggestions? I was using a BorderLayout and it just looked awkward. SCALING is very important.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you give me some suggestions?

- Avoid [*absolute positioning*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).
- Start with an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and modify it to exhibit any problem(s) you encounter.

[image: LayoutTest]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10867400/230513 */
public class LayoutTest extends JPanel {

    public LayoutTest() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        this.add(slider);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label", JLabel.CENTER);
        this.add(label);
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField("Text");
        this.add(jtf);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("LayoutTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LayoutTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```